# Ionic 3: Filetransfer download, file not in directory but no error code

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I'm trying to download an image with my Ionic3-App via the cordova FileTransfer plugin and store it on my device at this.file.dataDirectory and later display it in my app.

I'm testing it on my android device.

When i try to download it, it seems to work, i get the path for the directory and my success alert fires but when i look for it in the file system, the file is not there.
The app is not running with livereload and i've already downgraded the Webview!

It would be cool if someone could find a solution for this.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-online',
  templateUrl: 'online.html'
})

export class OnlinePage {

  private alert:any;
  public fileUrl:any = '';


  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public alertCtrl: AlertController, 
    private file: File, 
    private transfer: FileTransfer) {
  }

    download(){
        this.downloadFile();
    }

    downloadFile(){
      let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      let url = 'http://example.com/png/example.png';

      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'Textmaterial_Homepage.pdf', true).then((entry) => {
        var imagePath = entry.toURL();
        this.fileUrl = normalizeURL(imagePath);
        this.showAlert("File was downloaded","Path: " + this.fileUrl);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.showAlert("File was not downloaded","Try again!");
      }
     );
    }

  }
```

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

Comment: the problem may be issued by using the method `normalizeURL()` , this has been reported here : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/normalizeurl-file-var-http-localhost-8080-var/108225

Comment: could you log this : ` normalizeURL(imagePath)` ?

Comment: @IsaamEL-GUERCH 
normalizer: file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/Textmaterial_Homepage.pdf
it did nothing to the original URL

Comment: @Isaam EL-GUERCH my problem just got resolved. The file management program on my device somehow just works when it is closed. Still thank you.